# 2 domain to the same site

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php, domain

I have 2 domains example.com and example.org and both point to the same site on Wordpress.
Generally we use only .org but i would like that if someone goes to example.com/donate (where I have my civicontribute page embedded) I would like them to be able to submit donations from there too.
Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe add a second domain under define domain url  in sicicrm.settings.php?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter if the visitor is redirected to the other domain? If it doesn't matter then I would just redirect at the web server level. If you're using apache for example you can do as described here with a .htaccess file in the root folder of wordpress. It will just change the .com to .org and keep the rest of the url intact. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565560/redirect-all-traffic-from-one-domain-to-another

Comment: Thank you.
I tried adding it to the current .htaccess file but nothing changed.

Comment: @netzih - It sounds like this is a web server configuration issue.  If adding something to .htaccess didn't help, then it's possible you're not running Apache, or that your Apache config is ignoring .htaccess.  Because it's not CiviCRM-specific, I don't think you'll get the best answers here!

Comment: And also recognize that if you are able to do exactly what you request above (2 domains) you will need to pay for a cert for example.com.